# How to get column data type or mode in dbt using jinja

Tags: google-bigquery, jinja2, dbt

I'm trying to write a macro in DBT to unpivot a table (I know there are macros available and I can use SQL to do this but I want to write the macro).

Is there a way I can get a column’s data type/mode in dbt? I’m trying to write a macro where if a column is an array it should be treated differently. Something like this:

```
{%- set cols = adapter.get_columns_in_relation(table) %}
{% for col in cols %}

    {{col.name}} AS 'field_name',

    {% if col.mode != 'REPEATED' %}
        CAST({{ col.column }} AS STRING) AS 'value'
    {% else %}
        ARRAY_TO_STRING({{ col.column }}) AS 'value'
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

I looked at this page but I’m not sure what the return type is and there’s something wrong with the code here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [dbt docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-classes#column), the `Column` class has `data_type` as a property. [BigQuery columns](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-classes#bigquery-columns) have  `mode` as a property which can be used to identify array columns. Once you get the column objects you can simply do:

```
{%- set cols = adapter.get_columns_in_relation(table) %}
{% for col in cols %}
    
    {% if col.mode.lower() == 'repeated' %}

        ARRAY_TO_STRING({{col.column}}) AS 'value'

    {%else%}

        CAST({{col.column}} AS STRING) AS 'value'

    {%endif%}

{%endfor%}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about selecting the datatype from information schema tables?

```
{%- set column_types -%}
select column_name, data_type 
from `your_project.your_dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` 
where table_name = '{{ table }}'
{%- endset -%}

{%- set results = run_query(column_types) -%}

{%- if execute -%}
    {% for col in results %}
        {% if col["data_type"] == 'ARRAY' %}
            ARRAY_TO_STRING({{ col["column_name"] }}) AS {{ value_name }}
        {% else %}
            CAST({{ col["column_name"] }} AS {{ cast_to }}) AS {{ value_name }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```